# The page size was not large enough to format the contents of an object in the report

Tags: asp.net, crystal-reports, subreport

I'm trying to generate a report using Crystal Reports which contains data of two tables. So I tried to add another header page and put each table in a sub-report for each header page. This works very nicely when I have a single page in my report. It works here:

[image: it works here]

But when I had many lines of data( table 1) ( more than 10  lines ), I got this error:

> Page header or footer longer than a page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Right Click on Details in crystal report
- Detail ->Paging
- Control Number of Rows

Comment: i solve it. i just limited rows number in Details and resize the Footer so it can handle th job

Answer (score 2):

1. Got to your main report
2. Right-click on the subreport you added
3. Click **Format sub-report**
4. Uncheck the **Can Grow** option